# Laravel collection stays empty on edit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

Hello i have to simulair edit functions in laravel

```
public function edit(FieldOfStudy $fieldOfStudy)
    {
        return view(self::VIEW_FOLDER . 'edit', [
            'item' => $fieldOfStudy,
        ]);
    }
```

and

```
 public function edit(Exercise $exercise)
    {
        return view(self::VIEW_FOLDER . 'edit', [
            'item' => $exercise,
            'talents' => Talent::orderBy('name')->pluck('id', 'name')->all(),
        ]);
    }
```

the first one returns no data but the second one does

First one

```
^ App\Models\FieldOfStudy {#2085 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: "field_of_studies"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Second one

```
App\Models\Exercise {#2067 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "exercises"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 9
        "talent_id" => 3
        "type" => 4
        "week" => 1
        "content" => """
          <p>Je hebt aangegeven je verder te willen ontwikkelen op het gebied van 'analyseren'. 
    Jouw TalentCoach gaat je de komende weken daarbij helpen en ondersteunen.  ▶
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          """
        "theme" => "Waar wil jij aan gaan werken? "
        "created_at" => "2017-12-01 13:03:45"
        "updated_at" => "2022-02-09 14:22:11"
        "excerpt" => "Van twijfelaar naar doorpakker. Effectief en efficient gedrag op basis van 
    analyse."
      ]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

the routes are als both recources

```
Route::resource('fieldofstudies', 'AdminFieldOfStudiesController')->except('show');
Route::resource('exercises', 'AdminExercisesController')->except('show');
```

Why is one empty and one full? If you need more data let me know. Thanks in advance. Both off the routes have data in the database with the id Laravel 8.

Comment: couldnt find an example in the docs but maybe you also need to pascalCase your resource? `resource('fieldOfStudies')` or stud_case it? did you try?

Comment: I stud_case it and it worked changed `Route::resource('field_of_studies', 'AdminFieldOfStudiesController')->except('show');` to `Route::resource('field_of_studies', 'AdminFieldOfStudiesController')->except('show');` Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stud_case the resource:

```php
Route::resource('field_of_studies', 'AdminFieldOfStudiesController')->except('show');
```